# Why is the variable `input` often marked special in Python syntax markers?

Tags: python, pytorch, jupyter

In many syntax highlighters (e.g. jupyter notebooks) the variable `input` is highlighted in python. Is there a reason for this? I've avoided using `input` as a variablename because I thought it did something special internally.

I'm asking because pytorch often uses "input" as a [variable in their tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-neural-networks-tutorial-py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is a [function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input).
This will happen as well with for example `list`.

It is recommended not to overwrite the build-in functions with own variables.

Comment: Someone should tell pytorch as many of their examples use input https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-neural-networks-tutorial-py

Comment: Nobody is stopping you. Feel free to go to https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/issues , and explain this issue.
You could go one step further, fork the repository, fix the problem, and create a pull request.

Comment: `input` appears most often in introductory Python scripts, allowing new users to interact with the code before they learn to use the command line, files, and GUI.  So `pytorch` might be forgiven for masking the builtin function.

Comment: @DanielMarchand PyTorch issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15394